# Calculus Made Easy Exercise 2 Question 10

Tags: calculus

In Calculus Made Easy, Chapter 5, Exercise II Question 10:

> (10) The greatest external pressure P that a tube can support without
>   collapsing is given by:
>
> $$P = \left(\frac{2E}{1-\sigma^2}\right)\frac{t^3}{D^3}$$
>
> where $E$ and $\sigma$ are constants $t$ is the thickness of the tube
>   and $D$ is its diameter. (This formula assumes that $4t$ is small
>   compared to $D$.) Compare the rate at which $P$ varies for a small change
>   of thickness and for a small change of diameter taking place
>   separately.

I originally took the question to mean I had to find the derivative with respect to $D$ and $t$ compare dot t but that wasn't the case. Instead in the answers(page 289) I found:

> $$\frac{\text{Rate of change of $P$ when $t$ varies}}{\text{Rate of change of $P$ when $D$ varies}} = \frac{-D}{t}$$

Observing my error I tried dividing the derivatives I calculated (which I'm not 100% sure are correct) getting:
$$\frac{\left(\frac{2E}{1-\sigma^2}\right)\frac{3t^2}{D^3}}{\left(\frac{2E}{1-\sigma^2}\right)\frac{t^3}{-3D^4}} = -\frac{9D}{t}.$$
This is almost the same as the answer, but where did the $-9$ go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative at the denominator is wrong: the derivative of $t^3D^{-3}$ with respect to $D$ is $t^3(-3D^{-4})$. Hence
$$\frac{\text{Rate of change of $P$ when $t$ varies}}{\text{Rate of change of $P$ when $D$ varies}} =
\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\left(ct^3D^{-3}\right)}{\frac{d}{dD}\left(ct^3D^{-3}\right)}=\frac{c3t^2D^{-3}}{ct^3(-3D^{-4})}=-\frac{D}{t}$$
where $c=\left(\frac{2E}{1-\sigma^2}\right)$.

Comment: I see! I just looked at my notes and it it looks like I made a mistake when converting -3(D^-4) into a fraction, putting the -3 in the denominator instead of the numerator! Thanks for your really concise and helpful answer.